# Pyrebase stream not closing

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, forceclose, keyboardinterrupt, pyrebase

I don't know why the firebase-rest-api and the pyrebase isn't closing the stream instance when KeyboardInterrupt exception is raised..

You can receive this exception in this loop code:

```py
from firebase import initialize_app
from typing import List


class MyStuffTracker(object):
    """Tracks changes of my stuff in Firebase, this a public db for tests."""
    _db = initialize_app({
        'apiKey': "AIzaSyBtwpgXl4QHGsFtjvpGRGccHA31Jp8HdZ8",
        'authDomain': "website-acca0.firebaseapp.com",
        'databaseURL': "https://website-acca0-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
        'projectId': "website-acca0",
        'storageBucket': "website-acca0.appspot.com",
        'messagingSenderId': "403032921703",
        'appId': "1:403032921703:web:c1d5dec6bd02c1a8a3a6c2",
        'measurementId': "G-QD36TFS9M5"
    }).database()

    my_stuff: List[dict] = None  # In my example my data is a list of some dictionaries

    @property
    def is_ready(self) -> bool:
        """
        Returns:
            bool: True if my stuff is ready for use
        """
        return self.my_stuff is not None

    def stream_handler(self, message):
        print("Got some update from the Firebase")
        # We only care if something changed
        if message["event"] in ("put", "patch"):
            print("Something changed")
            if message["path"] == "/":
                print("Seems like a fresh data or everything have changed, just grab it!")
                self.my_stuff: List[dict] = message["data"]
            else:
                print("Something updated somewhere, I dont't care I just want the latest snapshot of my stuff")
                # Just get whole-data of my stuff and list (second) item of the pyres (that I expect to be a dict)
                self.my_stuff: List[dict] = list(it.item[1] for it in self._db.get().pyres)
            print(tracker.my_stuff)

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        """Start tracking my stuff changes in Firebase"""
        super().__init__()
        self._db.stream(self.stream_handler)


tracker = MyStuffTracker()

while True:
    pass
```

It's not closed...

If remove the while, the code is inclosable, I need to go to the task manager to close the python...

I know that I need to run the close method to close the stream, but when the keyboardinterrupt exception was raised, don't have a way to close anymore

I see that it solved:

```py
tracker = MyStuffTracker()
try:
    while True:
        pass
finally:
    tracker.close()
```

but it seans a little wrong, because if its closed out of the try, the code will enter on a loop on the same way...